# Auto-format for \ref, \cite

Tags: texstudio

Is there a way of getting texstudio to insert

```
~\cite
```

instead of `\cite{}`, as well as

```
 ~(\ref{})
```

instead of just `\ref{}`, similar to Emacs/AucTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that with `Macros -> Edit Macros`.

**Simple solution: Insert text on trigger**

Everytime you type the trigger `rref` the given text will be inserted (`%|` denoting the desired cursor position):

[image]

**Advanced solution: Script text insertion and start completer**

Instead of simply inserting text, you may run a script. In that case, you have to reposition the cursor explicitly, but you can start the completer afterwards.

[image]

*Note*: Actually the trigger is a RegExp and you could trigger on `\\ref`, however this may interfere with the completer and triggers are currently not guaranteed to work while the completer is running. This problem does not occur if you would have deactivated automatic opening of the compeleter in the options. Regardless of this, pure lowercase character triggers like `rref` are faster to type, which is the reason I prefer them.

For more information on scripting see the [TXS user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33).